# How to add a dropdown list to google sheet using Google Sheets API python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

Using `Google Sheets API python` How to add a `dropdown list` to google sheet with `list items` [YES. NO, MAYBE] for an invite asking friends if they will attend an event.

I looked at google developer sheets api documentation [HERE](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#datavalidationrule) and no example was provided.

Looking for the JSON structure.

The result would be something like this :

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the trick inside the `setDataValidation` property and choosing `ONE_OF_LIST` as the `condition type` and all I had to do is providing the list of items inside the `value` list

```
{
  "setDataValidation": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": sheet_id,
      "startRowIndex": 1,
      "endRowIndex": 1,
      "startColumnIndex": 22,
      "endColumnIndex": 23
    },
    "rule": {
      "condition": {
        "type": 'ONE_OF_LIST',
        "values": [
          {
          "userEnteredValue": 'YES',
          },
          {
          "userEnteredValue": 'NO',
          },
          {
          "userEnteredValue": 'MAYBE',
          },
        ],
      },
      "showCustomUi": True,
      "strict": True
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: worth mentioning that this type of data validation rule do not accept more than 500 elements into the list.

Comment: Here is the doc https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#setdatavalidationrequest

Comment: can I pass the entire dictionary above to `spreadsheet_obj.update_ranges`?