# create dropdown in exported csv file in Javascript

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, react-redux, export-to-csv

I am exporting CSV file in Reactjs where I need to create dropdown in generated CSV file

I tried `excel.js` and `shell.js` as well as csvlink download

```
<CSVLink data={data}>Download me</CSVLink>;
```

it showing normal csv with key value pair

Answer (score 0):

CSV file doesn't allow to use anything like dropdown. If you want a dropdown you need to use spreadsheet format.

Spreadsheets allows to have data validation:

[Dropdown in google sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

[Dropdown in Excel](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/)

Here is code sample from Python:
[How to add a dropdown list to google sheet using Google Sheets API python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429396/how-to-add-a-dropdown-list-to-google-sheet-using-google-sheets-api-python/43442775)

Comment: is it possible in spredsheet to add dropdown

Comment: @shweta spreadsheets allows to have data validation. I'm not sure if you can code it that way with any library (possible can) but:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/